# MassTransit + Azure service bus publish subscribe

Tags: c#, .net, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics

I created a service based on MassTransit that subscribes to a topic on azure service bus. Service that publishes messages is not based on MassTransit.

When trying to consume messages I get such exception:

> MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Transport.Receiver Error: 0 : Received faulted: 43d2f132ea034115ac6916fce77206a6, System.ArgumentException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. The specified HTTP verb (GET) is not valid. -> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

This is my host configuration:

```
var host = cfg.Host(options.ServiceBusConnectionString,
hst =>
{
    hst.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
    hst.TransportType = TransportType.NetMessaging;
});
```

I created also a subscriber using azure service bus native API and it receives published messages without problems. However, I want to use MassTransit:)

I searched through the web for the answers for this but there are not much information. So I am stuck and wondering if this is azure service bus configuration issue or I did not configured correctly the bus.

Comment: So, I suppose *don't use MassTransit* is not a valid answer? ;)  Service Bus already is your...well...service bus.  What will MassTransit give you that will offset the already introduced complication?  Really, I'm just curious.

Comment: This article explains why you might want to use MassTransit on top of ASB...http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/understand/additions-to-transport.html

Comment: sharing a bit more code around the bus initialization, consumer logic, and message contract would help a lot.